# TUF Gaming X570-Plus - No sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, motherboard, 21.04

I cannot get my speakers to play any sound from this motherboard: `TUF Gaming X570-Plus`.  On my speakers I tried the 3.5mm line and the S/PDIF line with no results.  I tried Ubuntu 20.04 and recently upgraded to 21.04 with no results.  I think this is a bug related to the motherboard.  My sound worked fine with the motherboard I had before this.

- The only system audio output device selection that makes sense for me
  is `Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller`
  with no results.
- The speakers are powered, my system tray sound is at 100%, the speakers are connected via S/PDIF.
- Sound works fine on my Windows 10 hard drive (same computer).